# Merging a lot of pdfs with pdf tk by name r

Tags: r, merge, pdftk

I have around 600 PDF's always in pairs. Those pairs always have the same name and I want to merge those 600 PDF's down to 300 PDF's. So that all the PDF's with the same name get merged in one. I want to use PDF TK but don't know how to code "same name".
Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide example filenames.

Comment: Everything from ACTICAM25.pdf to numbered sequenzes like DE767688. It is pretty random^^

Comment: "Same names" are they then in different folders?

Comment: yes. Two folders filled with 300 files all named like the ones in the other folder